# Android storage permission

Tags: android, account-security

There are a number of apps which ask for storage permission in Android. However it is unclear exactly what parts of storage are they able to access with this permission. As an example, would an app granted storage permission be able to access:

1. Photos
2. Files in Dropbox
3. Files in Google Drive
4. Any file, photo or document anywhere on the phone

I thought Android was sandboxing apps which would imply that an app should at least not be able to access personal files under Dropbox as an example.

What parts of the directory does storage permission give access to?